# Trying to split up my HTML files without leaving the main page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm building a web application and I am using the following code to render some nice popup forms.

```
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="addregion_form"></a>
<div class="popup">
    <h2>Add Region</h2>
    <a class="closeBut" href="Main.html#close" ng-click="showAdminMenuContainer()"></a>
</div>
```

By now my application, which is all in **main.html** has grown too big and i want to put this kind of stuff in separate HTML files. And link to my popup like this:

```
<div class="addbutton">                       
     <div>                            
          <a href="AddRegion.Html#addregion_form" id="addregion_pop">ADD</a>                            
     </div>
</div>
```

Adding the separate file **AddRegion.html** works, but the popup jumps to a complete empty screen. Out of the main page. Basically I want to work with nice small files which are somehow embedded in the **main.html** and still be able to refer to them like this:

```
<a href="#addregion_form" id="addregion_pop">ADD</a>
```

I already tried adding them in the 'head'section, but that doesn't seem to do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

You should attach event listeners in javascript and perform some actions when a user for example clicks "ADD" link.
Then you can load some other html files via XHR (XMLHttpRequest) to your document.

You can also build html structures in only javascript and then append them to the document.

Best way for you is to use some javascript framework like jquery. You already have some angularjs attributes bind to `<a>` tag and if it's not accident check angularjs documentation.
If it doesn't matter use jquery. Its much more simple on start :)

For example if it was jquery and you would like to load other html file you could add this code before ending body tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#addregion_pop').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
            url: 'AddRegion.html',
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',                
            success: function (response) {
                $(body).append(response);
            }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Yes this turned out the best solution for me!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Mr Lister was working fine. 
using Jquery to include HTML files

I did the following;

- include j-query main script
- added this small function

  `$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Panel").load("/Partials/Panel.html");
  $("#WelcomeText").load("/Partials/WelcomeText.html");
  });`
- Added a div that referenced like thi`<div id ="Panel"> </div>`

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are using Angular (your code has `ng-click`). I suggest you look into https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router. It allows you to do exactly what you want: a single `main.html` file and separate, small chunk of code in separate files (divide and conquer, separation of concerns :)

I hope that helps.

If the answer pointed you in the right direction, don't forget to mark the answer as `accepted` :D

Comment: Hi, I've ended up looking at angular indeed. I use it to communicate with my webservice. 

Angular hag ng-include. 

I've added the following on the top of my mainpage

<ng-include src="'/Partials/AddRegion.html'"></ng-include>

But this results in a malfunctioning website. All other pop ups are not working anymore. When i remove this code it works fine again. 

I cannot find a solution to this... any ideas?